# Magento Indexer not working even using the CLI

Tags: php, mysql, magento, pdo, indexer

I've been trying to fix the Indexer and follow steps like going to php admin, dropping a specific table and importing back without constraints, I tried working on the var/locks though I don't have that kind of folder in my directories, creating a php script to reindex. And lastly I tried the CLI/SSH until I encounter this one:

```html
Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#8 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#9 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#10 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1) ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 0, 1, cisi.is_in_stock), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
`inner`.`customer_group_id`,
`inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)' in /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /chroot/home/user/userproducts.com/html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
```

I tried reading and understanding but it's just leading me to something that I don't really understand. I'm not magento expert, I'm just reading and trying what magento experts suggest though most of it is out of my coverage skill set.

Looking forward for your help. Thanks!